# Next to generate a list of 12 months from a selected value in a slicer

Tags: dax

I have a table with column contract period with values like ‘August 2020 - July 2021’ ,’August 2021 - July 2022’ ,’August 2022 - July 2023’ .This column is used in a slicer.Now I need to have a dynamic header to a table with 12 months in a contractual period,whenever I change the contract period value in slicer,12 months in the header should change accordingly

I tried to get a value in slicer using selected value function and extracted the first 10 letters like ‘August 2020’ and converted this to date using date value,using add columns and format function tried to get the list of 12 months ,but it didn’t worked